# delete xml information / reference without losing structure

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I'm currently working on a project that builds catalogs.
The catalogs consist of several different, linked INDD-files.
Now, those INDD-files are filled up with XML data and saved.
When we import them, we always get errors that there is a link missing to the xml. Now, once the indd is filled up, we do not need the xml reference anymore.
I've checked the links-page in indesign, to see if there is a reference to the xml but there is none...

How can I delete all the xml information from a indesign file without loosing the references to a text box or it's structure..

Thanks

Regards

Mario

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible through InDesign. I know you can export your document as IDML, extract the Zip package, and delete what you need from the XML folder, but I don't think that will affect the InDesign document - once you export the IDML I think it is independent of the original InDesign document.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible? :)

Check out this artcile, [Removing the XML Structure from a document](http://indesignsecrets.com/removing-the-xml-structure-from-a-document.php).

Hope this helps!